# Let A be a subset of a metric space (X,d). Prove that A is open in X iff no sequence in X−A can converge to a point of A

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Question: Let $\mathit A$ be a subset of a metric space $\mathit (X,d) $. Prove that $\mathit A$ is open in $\mathit X$ iff no sequence in $\mathit X-A$ can converge to a point of $\mathit A$.

My attempt:

Let, $\mathit A$ be open in $\mathit X$,
that is $$\mathit (X-A)^c=A$$ is open in X.

$\implies$$\mathit (X-A)$ is closed in $\mathit X$.

$\implies$$\mathit (X-A)$ contains all its limit points.

Let, if possible, $$\mathit <x_n>$$ be a sequence in $\mathit (X-A)$, which converges to x∈$\mathit A$.

$\implies$for any $\epsilon$>0 ,there exist n($\epsilon$)∈$\Bbb N$ such that

$$\mathit x_n∈\mathit S(x,\epsilon)$$ for all n$\geqslant$n($\epsilon$).

$\implies$every open sphere centered at x contains infinitely many points $x_n$ of $\mathit (X-A)$.

$\implies$x is a limit point of $\mathit (X-A)$,Which is a contradiction as $\mathit (X-A)$ is closed.

$\implies$the sequence $x_n$ in $\mathit (X-A)$ is not converges to x∈$\mathit A$.As $$\mathit <x_n>$$ in $\mathit (X-A)$ and x∈$\mathit A$ are arbitrary.So, no sequence in $\mathit (X-A)$ is converge to a point of $\mathit A$.

Conversely, Suppose, no sequence in $\mathit (X-A)$ is converge to a point of $\mathit A$,that is all convergence sequence in $\mathit (X-A)$ are converges to a point of $\mathit (X-A)$.

So,Let $$\mathit <x_n>$$ in $\mathit (X-A)$ converge to a point $x_0$∈$\mathit (X-A)$.

$\implies$for any $\epsilon$>0 ,there exist n($\epsilon$)∈$\Bbb N$ such that

$$\mathit x_n∈\mathit S(x_0,\epsilon)$$ for all n$\geqslant$n($\epsilon$).

$\implies$every open sphere centered at $x_0$ contains infinitely many points $x_n$ of $\mathit (X-A)$.

$\implies$$\mathit (X-A)$ contains all its limit points as $x_0$ is arbitrary.

$\implies$$\mathit (X-A)$ is closed.

$\implies$ $$\mathit (X-A)^c=A$$ is open in $\mathit A$.

//  Please someone point out my mistake. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: *Do* you think there's a mistake? Or are you just asking for proof verification?

Comment: I think my converse part is not good enough. So I want someone to verify the proof and if something wrong, please provide some hints.

Comment: OK; I've added the `proof-verification` tag to draw more eyeballs in.

Comment: Or tried to. Weird; is the limit four tags? I thought it was five...

Comment: I think we can add five tags but I have little knowledge about this platform.

Comment: Your argument for the first implication could be improved by simply assuming that $\{x_n\}$ sequence of points in $A^c$ that converges to $x \in A$. Then we have an immediate contradiction as $A$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $x_n \notin A$ for every $n$.

Comment: As for the converse, you should start by assuming that $x_0$ is a limit point of $A^c$ that is not an isolated point of $A$. Since $x_0$ is not an isolated point, that means every neighborhood of $x_0$ contains a point $x_n \neq x_0$.

Comment: @MAPelto Thanks for the suggestion. I will post an answer in few hours.